# Generalized limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, convergence-acceleration

*Cross-posted [to Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345164/generalized-limits).*

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Lim}{Lim}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\shift}{\sigma}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\cesaro}{C}$

After reading Terry Tao's post on [generalizations of the limit functional](https://terrytao.wordpress.coem/2017/05/11/generalisations-of-the-limit-functional/), I'm interested in the concept of a "generalized limit", which agrees with the ordinary limit when the latter exists, but also extends it to new sequences.

Let $X$ be a metrized module. A generalized limit is a partial function from sequences of elements of $X$ to $X$:
$$\Lim : \bigcup_{S \subseteq X^\mathbb{N}} X^S$$

Let $\lim$ be the Cauchy limit. That is, $\lim x = a$ iff
$$\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+ : \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \in \mathbb{N} : n > N \rightarrow d(x(n),a) < \varepsilon$$

$\Lim_1$ is weaker than $\Lim_2$ iff
$$\Lim_1 \subseteq \Lim_2$$

$\Lim$ is regular iff it is stronger than $\lim$. $\Lim_1$ is consistent with $\Lim_2$ iff
$$\forall x \in (\dom \Lim_1 \cap \dom \Lim_2) : \Lim_1(x) = \Lim_2(x)$$

$\Lim$ is homogeneous iff
$$\forall a \in X : \forall x \in \dom \Lim: \Lim(a x) = a \Lim(x)$$

$\Lim$ is additive iff
$$\forall x, y \in \dom \Lim : \Lim(x + y) = \Lim(x) + \Lim(y)$$

$\Lim$ is linear iff it is homogeneous and additive. $\Lim$ is stable iff
$$\Lim = \Lim \circ \shift$$

where $\shift : X^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow X^\mathbb{N}$ is the shift transform defined by
$$\shift(a)(n) = a(n+1)$$

---

If $a \neq 1$ and $\Lim$ is stable and homogeneous, then $\Lim (n \mapsto a^n) = 0$. Proof:
\begin{align}
    \Lim (n \mapsto a^n)
    &= (\Lim \circ \shift) (n \mapsto a^n) & \text{(stability)} \\
    &= \Lim(\shift(n \mapsto a^n)) \\
    &= \Lim(n \mapsto a^{n+1}) \\
    &= \Lim(a (n \mapsto a^n)) \\
    &= a \Lim(n \mapsto a^n) & \text{(homogeneity)} \\
    (1 - a) \Lim(n \mapsto a^n) &= 0 \\
    \Lim(n \mapsto a^n) &= 0
\end{align}

Note that if $a$ is prime then this yields the correct [$a$-adic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order). This also yields the expected generalized sum of a geometric series:
\begin{align}
    \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n
    &= \Lim\left(m \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^m a^n\right) \\
    &= \Lim\left(m \mapsto \frac{1-a^{m+1}}{1-a}\right) \\
    &= \frac{1 - \Lim(m \mapsto a^{m+1})}{1-a} \\
    &= \frac{1}{1-a} \\
\end{align}

Consequently, if $\Lim$ is stable and linear then
\begin{align}
  \Lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cos n
  &= \Lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{in} + \mathrm{e}^{-in}}{2} \\
  &= \frac{\Lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\mathrm{e}^{i})^n + \Lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\mathrm{e}^{-i})^n}{2} \\
  &= 0
\end{align}

and the same is true of $\sin$, we also have
\begin{align}
  \Lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^m \cos n
  &= \Lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\cos(m)}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cot \frac{1}{2} \sin m\right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{2} \\
  \Lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^m \sin n
  &= \Lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{1}{2} \cot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin m}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos m \cot \frac{1}{2}\right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{2} \cot \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

More generally, if $a \neq 1$ and $\Lim$ is stable and linear then
\begin{align}
  \Lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^m a^n n^b
  &= \Lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} (\mathrm{Li}_{-b}(a) - a^{m+1} \Phi(a,-b,m+1)) \\
  &= \mathrm{Li}_{-b}(a) + \Lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} a^{m+1} \Phi(a,-b,m+1) \\
  &= \mathrm{Li}_{-b}(a)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  \Lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^m a^n n!
  &= \Lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \left( -\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-1/a} \Gamma(0,-1/a)}{a} + (-1)^{m+1} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-1/a} \Gamma(-m-1,-1/a) (m+1)!}{a} \right) \\
  &= -\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-1/a} \Gamma(0,-1/a)}{a} + \Lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} (-1)^{m+1} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-1/a} \Gamma(-m-1,-1/a) (m+1)!}{a} \\
  &= -\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-1/a} \Gamma(0,-1/a)}{a}
\end{align}

where $\mathrm{Li}$ is the polylogarithm and $\Phi$ is the Lerch transcendent. Thus the properties of stability and linearity alone make the generalized limit quite powerful.

**Question:** Is there a $\Lim$ such that

1. $\Lim$ can be explicitly defined in terms of the Cauchy limit, e.g. $\Lim = \lim \circ f$ where $f$ is some sequence transform.
2. $\Lim$ is stronger than (i.e. contains) the *stable and linear closure* of the Cauchy limit.

---

The Cesàro transform $\cesaro : X^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow X^\mathbb{N}$ yields the sequence of partial averages:
$$\cesaro(a)(n) = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n a(k)$$

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let the $n$-Cesàro limit be the Cauchy limit of the Cesàro transform iterated $n$ times:
$$\lim \circ \cesaro^n$$

The $n$-Cesàro limit is regular, linear, and stable. Moreover,
$$\lim \circ \cesaro^n \subsetneq \lim \circ \cesaro^{n+1}$$

The inclusion is proper as can be seen by taking the sequence
$$k \mapsto (-1)^k k^n$$

which is in the domain of the latter but not the former. Let the $\omega$-Cesàro limit be the union of all such limits:
$$\bigcup_{n < \omega} \lim \circ \cesaro^n$$

That is, the $\omega$-Cesàro limit is the closure of the Cauchy limit under Cesàro transforms.

My question is this: Are there any interesting examples of linear limits that are (non-strictly) stronger than the $\omega$-Cesàro limit? What about stronger than the closure of the $\omega$-Cesàro limit under stability (shift transforms)? This last property would allow it to regularize geometric limits. **Note:** It would not have to be stable itself, just stronger than the stable closure of the $\omega$-Cesàro limit.

I suspect sequence transformations used to accelerate the rate of convergence of sequences, like the [Shanks transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_transformation) and [Aitken's delta-squared process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitken%27s_delta-squared_process), might be useful here.

Comment: Not sure why you give special names to the invariance properties you are assuming for your $Lim$ operator, also if $Lim(a^n)$ exists and $a \ne 0$ then $Lim(a^n)  =0$ (with the usual $\lim$ then $\lim 2^n$ doesn't exist and $\lim 1^n= 1$). Also you didn't define the "iterated Cesaro limit". Do you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^n (n-k)^n a_k}{\sum_{k=0}^n k^n}$ or $Lim a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} (C^m a)_n$ if it exists for some $m$ ?

Comment: @reuns I don’t understand your first sentence regarding naming. Regarding your second sentence, did you mean $a \neq 1$? I proved this in my question. Regarding your third sentence, I did define the iterated Cesàro mean right below the definition of the Cesàro transform (it’s the same as your second expression).

Comment: @reuns Actually, I think I know what you meant now. I edited the question.

Comment: this can be rephrased in terms of "divergent series" since any sequence $a_n$ can be written as a partial sum of the differences $a_{n+1} - a_n$. If the $\omega$-Cesaro limit is nothing but "find an $m$ where $C^m$ works, then use it", then I believe the Abel regularisation

$$\lim_A : a \mapsto a_0 + \lim_{x\to 1}  \sum_{i=1}^\infty (a_{n} - a_{n-1} ) x^n = \lim_{x\to 1} (1-x) \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n x^n $$

is regular, homogeneous, additive, stable, and stronger than  $\omega$-Cesaro. There are yet others in Hardy's book on Divergent Series

Comment: (In particular theorem 56 on page 108 of Hardy. Though I haven't properly checked that it does apply to sequences, I don't see why not)

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345164/generalized-limits

Comment: The link does not work for me.

Comment: @user76284 Sorry for replying to an old question of yours but the later part of it interested me. If you don't mind, may I ask where did you read about the properties of iterated Cesàro transform? Linearity and regularity is not hard to see for $n$-Cesàro mean but it is not obvious to me that it is stable. Seeing the general treatment of such a subject would be nice.

Comment: @BigbearZzz G. H. Hardy's *Divergent Series* is considered the standard reference for this subject. I don't remember the exact reference for this particular property, but Cesàro summation is a special case of Nørlund means, which as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#N%C3%B8rlund_means) are stable.

Comment: @user76284 Very interesting, thank you very much. I'll definitely have a look into that.

Comment: @user76284 I cannot find any proof in Hardy's book about regularity of Nørlund means at all, unfortunately. Wikipedia article also doesn't provide reference to their claim regarding the stability of Nørlund means.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Regarding regularity, Nørlund means are themselves a special case of matrix summability methods. The [Silverman–Toeplitz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverman%E2%80%93Toeplitz_theorem) characterizes the conditions under which a matrix summability method is regular.

Comment: @user76284 I'm truly sorry but I meant to say stability, not regularity. Regardless, Hardy did indeed prove that iterated Cesàro mean is stable so my initial question was answered so I thank you for pointing me to the book. I still don't know Nørlund means really are stable in general though. It's not that important to me but would be nice to know regardless.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Theorems 5.33 and 5.34 of [*The Nörlund and the weighted mean methods*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-81-322-2559-1_5) by P. N. Natarajan characterize the conditions for being translative (i.e. stable), citing *Translativity of weighted means in non-archimedean fields*, also by P. N. Natarajan.